# Modify blocks layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of element, I would like to re-arrange with flexbox.
Here is a [JPEG Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGTsS.jpg) of the result before/after I would like to achieve.

HTML :

```
<ul>
  <li class="bloc1" style="background:#9fcfff;">Bloc 1</li>
  <li class="bloc2" style="background:#ffc39f;">Bloc 2</li>
  <li class="bloc3" style="background:#b4e7a7;">Bloc 3</li>
  <li class="bloc4" style="background:#ff9ff9;">Bloc 4</li>
  <li class="bloc5" style="background:#f3eda9;">Bloc 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
ul {
  height:200px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background:#eeeeee;
  display: -ms-flexbox; 
  display: flex; 
  -ms-flex-direction: row; 
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: start; 
}
li {
  list-style:none; 
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
  width:33.33%;
  height:50px;
}
.bloc1 {order:1;height:100px;}
.bloc2 {order:2;}
.bloc3 {order:4;}
.bloc4 {order:3;}
.bloc5 {order:5;}
```

I made a [Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRjEzJ)

I don't know how to do now.
Not sure if I have to specify a height for parent container and/or children.
Or maybe what I want to do is not possible (?)

Thanks in advance for your help ! :)

Comment: Sorry my "Hello" disappeared ! :) :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is difficult if not impossible in Flexbox without specifiying a height or changing the HTML structure. CSS Grid could fix this in a jiffy though.

Comment: even if this can be done with flex i agree with @Paulie_D that grid is more suitable for such situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQyjNo)

---

**Relevant CSS**

```
ul {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}

li {
  list-style:none; 
  text-align:center;
  width:30%;
  flex: 48% 0 1;
}


.bloc1 { flex: 100% 0 1; }
```

---

**How it works**

The divs inside the flexbox container are arranged in columns and the first one have a `flex-basis` set to `100%` so it can take all the vertical space. All the other divs have this property set to a value a bit lower than 50% so there is some room available between blocks (of course this value can be modified as you wish)

The main container have set `space-between` as the value of `justify-content` and `align-content` (both the main and cross-axis should show some space between the blocks) and `flex-wrap` set to wrap.

---

**Final result**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may use direction column since you **specified a fixed height** to `ul` (the container) and then adjust height/order of elements as needed:

```css
ul {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eeeeee;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50%;
}

.bloc1 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bloc1" style="background:#9fcfff;">Bloc 1</li>
  <li class="bloc2" style="background:#ffc39f;">Bloc 2</li>
  <li class="bloc3" style="background:#b4e7a7;">Bloc 3</li>
  <li class="bloc4" style="background:#ff9ff9;">Bloc 4</li>
  <li class="bloc5" style="background:#f3eda9;">Bloc 5</li>
</ul>
```